# How to apply a multiplier to particular searched values in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a table of values with 2 different columns say x and y, if a value in the y column = 0 then I need to apply a multiplier to the x column and vice versa. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, so far Ive tried to use an if else statement to sort of catch any values of 0 in one of the columns so for example...........

if in df 'Unnamed: 2' ==0:
    1.47*'Unnamed: 3' 
else:
    none 

........my python knowledge is very limited so im sorry if thats hard to decipher. Im almost certain its nowhere near correct lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use slicing on rows with [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to modify each column:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,0,2,0], 'y':[1,3,0,4]})
df.loc[df['x'] == 0, 'y'] = df.loc[df['x'] == 0, 'y'] * 2
df.loc[df['y'] == 0, 'x'] = df.loc[df['y'] == 0, 'x'] * 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and but put in my own column names so i now have (sorry i dont know how to write in code format)..... 

df=pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 2':[1,0,2,0],'Unnamed: 3':[1,3,0,4]})
df.loc[df.x == 0, 'Unnamed: 3'] = df.loc[df.x== 0, 'Unnamed: 3']* 2
df.loc[df.y == 0, 'Unnamed: 2'] = df.loc[df.y== 0, 'Unnamed: 2']* 2

....... but now i just receive the error message    ........ AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'x'..........

I cant name my columns x and y because the txt file has them down as 'Unnamed: 2' and 'Unnamed: 3' which both have spaces in.

Comment: I just slightly modified my answer to give you an hint in the right direction ;-)

Comment: Thanks Guillaume I really appreciate it :)